# Android ImageButton Size doesn't fit on smaller screen device

Tags: android, imagebutton

I want to know how to set my application contents so that they can be fixed in at least 3.5 inch devices.

It is looking like this in such smaller size device (4 inches).

As shown in this image, all four image buttons are overlapping each other & look good in 7 inch screen.
Is there any way to fix this problem?

[image]

This is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg2"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".StartActivity" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/abc" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/nmbrs" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/vegebtns" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/fruitsbtn" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: actually what type design you expect ?

Comment: Do you want to change the size of the buttons if the screen size is a determinated size. like 3,5 or 4?

Comment: D you need an overlapped design?

Comment: your are using larger images. it make wrapperContent to their size

Comment: @user3197977 Where is your link?

Comment: @giacomoni yes i want button according to the image size. actually i am posting link of my snap which getting problem

Comment: @Tobor sorry please try now.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create values Folder for each type of screen.
2. Create dimens.xml file in every folder
3. create dimens values for button width and height in every folder with same name
4. change `android:layout_width="@dimens/name"`

better to refer http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

Use every image button like as follows

```
    <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/fruitsbtn" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change some image or size according to the size of the screen (not dpi), you can use the following method:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
double x = Math.pow(dm.widthPixels/dm.xdpi,2);
double y = Math.pow(dm.heightPixels/dm.ydpi,2);
double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x+y);
if(screenInches > sizeYouWant){
    //do what you want
}
```